# Return Stored Proc Results in CTE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

Is it possible for me to call a stored proc into a CTE. I have a login to our reporting DB that is only RO. I have write access to our UAT but would like to query live data.

So can I use a stored proc in a CTE?

```
with clientOwes as (
  exec des_Batch_GetApplicationClientOwesList
)     
select a.des_applicationnumber 
from des_heapplicationset a 
where a.des_heapplicationid in (select applicationid from clientowes)
```

> result was: *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.*

Comment: Do you want to use the result of `SP` in `CTE`

Comment: You might be able to use OPENROWSET for this.  See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Comment: @NoDisplayName:  Yes, I would like the result in the CTE.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Why do you need a CTE?  Are you calling the stored procedure with different inputs every time?  You're going to execute that procedure once for each row with this approach.  I understand your access problem but if you tell us more about your goal we might be able to help you with a better solution.

Comment: @TabAlleman

`with clientOwes as (
exec des_Batch_GetApplicationClientOwesList
) 

select a.des_applicationnumber 
from des_heapplicationset a 
where a.des_heapplicationid in (select applicationid from clientowes)`

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'

Comment: And?   What happens when you execute that query?   You might want to edit your original question and add the query you tried and the result you got.

Comment: @jtimperley I am using a CTE because it's RO.  I suppose I could use the stored proc directly in the WHERE using an IN (SELECT...) but I don't know if that works either.

Is it possible to use a stored Proc in the WHERE statement of a SELECT query?

Comment: You can use a stored proc to populate a table variable, which I think you can do with RO access.

Comment: @TabAlleman That would solve the problem for sure.  Do I have to do that with the OpenRowSet or is there another method to populate a table variable (with RO access)?

Comment: No need for OpenRowSet, just INSERT INTO MyTableVariable EXEC MyStoredProc

Comment: @TabAlleman I'll give that a try with my RO access.  I don't have server access to change DB settings so we'll see how this works (i.e. is allowed) .

Comment: Depending on how many rows you expect back, I'd suggest using a temptable over a table variable.

Comment: I'll research the difference between the two and see what limitations my environment has in store for me.  Will report back with results.

Comment: @TabAlleman how do I select your comment for an answer?  Or do I copy and paste into the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer adapted from dialogue in comments:

You can use a stored procedure to populate a table variable, which Read Only access does allow you to create.  You won't need to use OpenRowSet to populate it either.   Just do:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTableVariable
EXEC MyStoredProcedure
```

I do this in a lot of places myself where I need to treat Stored Proc results as a table that I can JOIN or UNION with other tables.